# Avoiding POT rule for Opengl Textures: Overlapp a transparent POT bitmap with non POT bitmap?

Tags: opengl-es, textures

i need to load non POT bitmaps into my opengl es app for android.

What i need is to overlap my non POT bitmap into another bitmap with POT size. I need to overlap the non POT bitmap in the center of the POT bitmap.

How can i do it?

i tryed with createScaledBitmap but it stretches the image and i dont want that.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this is not projecting a NPOT onto a POT, but loading a POT and manipulating the UV coordinates accordingly in the texture Coordinates buffer. Right now you probably have somthing like this:

```
private float textureCoords[] = {
        0.0f, 1.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, 0.0f          
};
```

For the UV mapping of the texture onto the quad. Changing the values to something other than 0.0 or 1.0 will crop accordingly. Make sure you choose these values right or some color will get into your image.